# Vuejs http interceptors fails

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to setup vuejs http interceptors but they dont work.

```
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api' //this works

Vue.http.interceptors.push({
  request: (request) => {
    console.log("we have a request")
    return request
  },
  response: (response) => {
    console.log('we got a response', response)
    return response
  },
  error: (err) => {
    console.log('error is', err)
  }
})
```

Now in my components

```
this.$http.get('user/profile/')
```

THe interceptors dont console.log

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the interceptors configured properly, you should be pushing a function with 2 arguments `request` and `next`.

```
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api' //this works

Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
  console.log(request)
  request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token'))
  next()
})

Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
  next(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
    if (response.status === 401) {
      // handle error or logout
      return response
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Sure. You can tick as answer so everyone knows it works

Comment: surely will do this.

Comment: Could you also show on how i can attach access token on the request?

Comment: I have that highlighted, you save the access token to sessionStorage when Authenticated successfully, you set the `request.headers.set('<replace-with-header-name>', '<replace-with-header-value>')` in interceptors to `request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access_token'))`, you can set any header value you'd like